# Can I carry a waveform generator with me inside an airplane?

Tags: airport, security, airplane, electronics

I have recently learned that I have an urgent domestic flight tonight. I am curious about whether I can carry the device with me. The device I want to carry is 33120A Arbitrary Waveform Generator. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: If you want a quick and accurate reply, ask your airline. Otherwise ask on [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) as passenger-related questions are off-topic here.

Comment: If it requires wall power and has a removable power cord, remove the cord. If it's a standard 3-prong PC-style cord, it's highly likely they'll have one you can borrow at your destination. If not, have a coworker carry it in his/her luggage (assuming someone else is traveling with you). If it's battery powered, leave the batteries at home and tell them to get you some at your destination. It can't cause harm if it can't be turned on.

Comment: Having a business card with "engineer" in the title works wonders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify a country for your domestic flight, but in general:

Assuming you do not intend to power it on and use it during the flight, it should not be a problem.   Esoteric and unusual electronics may get a bit more screening by security services, but should not be explicitly banned.

I recommend allowing extra time for security screening, and it may help if you have instruction manuals and other documentation to help security understand what the device is and why it is not a threat.

Comment: Also they may want you to fire it up.